# Switch forever logs without stopping forever service

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, forever, logrotate

We are using forever in our production environment and when trying to rotate the logs my forever process is killed even though I'm using copytruncate.
Now, I can bypass this by restarting the forever service in my postrotate scripts, but I wanted to know whether there is a command to change to forever log file.
Something like - forever restart -l new_log.log app.js

Is there any way to do something like this? or is stopping and starting the forever process an absolute neccesity?

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, stopping and restarting is necessary.
I'd definitely recommend using [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) instead. It offers the same as `forever` and much much more. It's also a lot easier to use. And it has a log-rotate plugin which automatically takes care of log rotation, completely hassle-free and fully configured as you want.

Comment: Thanks, PM2 does look like a better option. Is it completely free? Their homepage looks a bit commercial...

Comment: Yeah, even beter it's OSS, you can find the source here: https://github.com/Unitech/pm2